# help on converting to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, c#-4.0

Can some one help me convert this to c#?

```
   //' Import the ODBC namespace for MySQL Connection  
   Imports System.Data.Odbc  
   Partial Class login  
       Inherits System.Web.UI.Page  

       Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login1.Authenticate  
           Dim cn As New OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydb; User=root;Password=;")  
           cn.Open()  
           Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("Select * from login where username=? and password=?", cn)  

           //'Add parameters to get the username and password  

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar)  
           cmd.Parameters("@username").Value = Me.Login1.UserName  

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar)  
           cmd.Parameters("@password").Value = Me.Login1.Password  

           Dim dr As OdbcDataReader  
           //' Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
           //' If row exists, the login is successful  

           dr = cmd.ExecuteReader  

           If dr.HasRows Then  
               e.Authenticated = True  
               //' Event Authenticate is true  
           End If  

       End Sub  
   End Class  
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code conversion service. Please take time to research: the two syntaxes are not that far apart. You can start by making your keywords lower-case and learn how to declare variables in C#. Then, you can even proceed from the compilation errors.

Comment: very sorry I didnt know about the code conversions and I thought stack overflow was a place you can get help? I will be sure not to post such things as I know about code conversions available thanks to the community.

Comment: Also, there were some manual alterations that were required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Import the ODBC namespace for MySQL Connection  
using System.Data.Odbc;
partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{



    protected void  
Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydb; User=root;Password=;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from login where username=? and password=?", cn);

        //Add parameters to get the username and password  

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;

        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);
        // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
        // If row exists, the login is successful  

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows) {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            // Event Authenticate is true  
        }

    }
}
```

you can use [this converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) for future conversions.

EDIT:

you'll have to wire up the event in c# like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Login1.Authenticate += Login1_Authenticate; 
}
```

Comment: jesus that was fast testing now

Comment: Dang it, got the same code from the same place.  Lol.

Comment: @Garrith: That's because @StackOverflowException undoubtedly used a tool like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ to provide this answer. (Not that there is anything wrong with that, +1 from me). Tools like this can be invaluable to save you some busy-work.

Comment: @Robaticus I think I would be discouraged if you got different code from the same place!

Comment: And now we have human proxies to web services. I wonder if he supports NTLM? ;)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Kerberos only, watch your hops!

Comment: @Quintin, true, but only if StackOverflowException actually wants to impersonate Garrith Graham on developerfusion :)

Comment: guys got three problems :( Paramters cannot be used like a method (altho pramaters.add is fine strange) and cmd.ExecuteReader (cannot convert method group?)

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteReader` should be `cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: ok thats fixed, now just the params?

Comment: ah, `cmd.Parameters("@password").Value` should be `cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value`

Comment: Also dont forget you'll have to add `Login1.Authenticate += Login1_Authenticate` in `Page_Load` or in page's designer.

Comment: getting this error: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: not sure which driver version I am (latest mysql release)

Comment: Check out this post http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial139_Connecting-to-MySQL-with-Csharp-and-ODBC.html

Comment: fixed I think least no errors. Now just need to figure out how to add a redirect on successful login

Answer (score 2):

Use this online tool,
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

Quick conversion using this site:  http://converter.telerik.com

It looks like an event handler, so you'll have to wire that up in your code as well.

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void  // ERROR: Handles clauses are not supported in C#
Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydb; User=root;Password=;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from login where username=? and password=?", cn);

        //Add parameters to get the username and password  

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters("@username").Value = this.Login1.UserName;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters("@password").Value = this.Login1.Password;

        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);
        // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
        // If row exists, the login is successful  

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader;

        if (dr.HasRows) {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            // Event Authenticate is true  
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other conversions look good, but the original code was a little weak in terms of closing / disposing of the database objects.  Here is a slightly refactored version that addresses those weaknesses:

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page


{

    protected void  // ERROR: Handles clauses are not supported in C#
    Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        using(OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydb; User=root;Password=;"));
        using(OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from login where username=? and password=?", cn))
        {
           cn.Open();

           //Add parameters to get the username and password  

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
           cmd.Parameters("@username").Value = this.Login1.UserName;

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
           cmd.Parameters("@password").Value = this.Login1.Password;

           // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
           // If row exists, the login is successful  

           using(OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader)
           {
             if (dr.HasRows) {
                 e.Authenticated = true;
               // Event Authenticate is true  
             }
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: Even better would be ditching ODBC in favor of the MySQL ADO.NET drivers.